# WSO2 API Manager - Upgrade 1.6.0 to 1.7.0

Tags: wso2, upgrade, wso2-api-manager

I have configured API Manager 1.6.0 with MySQL.
I have tried to run the version 1.7.0 with same conections and I have several errors like this

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'wso2_apiManagerdb.IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE' doesn't exist
```

Exists any documentation for migrate?
Thanks

Comment: Drop MySQL database????
It is not a new installation. 
I can not lose the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the migration script here at [1].

[1] - https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.7.0/modules/distribution/resources/migration-1.6.0_to_1.7.0/

Answer (score 0):

Please use the migration scripts found in the following location

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.7.0/modules/distribution/resources/migration-1.6.0_to_1.7.0/

Comment: Thanks Nadeesha. The schema upgrade is correct and I not received more the error. I see my APIs created on MySQL.
But when I click on API Publisher over one API, I can see this error in the console.


[2014-05-27 08:41:17,123] ERROR - ApplicationDispatcher Servlet.service() for servlet JaggeryServlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:451)


In addition to modifying the database schema.
I should make more actions for the upgrade?

Comment: Another thing.
I can see the APPs on Store and Publisher.
But don't appears on Admin Console.
Is strangely.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions given in the readme file https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.7.0/modules/distribution/resources/migration-1.6.0_to_1.7.0/README.txt

Comment: Sorry. I had not seen the document. I'll read it and I tell you something.

Comment: I have followed the intructions of readme.
But the same thing keeps happening.
I can see the APPs on Publisher. But don't appears on Admin Console and Store. 
And when click on API Store or Publisher I see this error

Comment: I have followed the readme. But the same thing keeps happening.I can see the APIs on Publisher. But don't appears on Admin Console and Store. And when I click on API Publisher over any API I see this error
ERROR - item-info:jag org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while getting API information of the api- BUSOtro-1.0.0
ERROR - RhinoEngine org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: ERROR - WebAppManager org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "name" from null (/publisher/site/themes/default/templates/item-info/template.jag#5)

Comment: Nadeesha,
thanks for the information.
I close this question and I open a new with the error.

Comment: @RafaHernández : I have answered in your other question related to this. There was a issue in the swagger migration scripts with this patch