# WSO2 API Manager 1.6.0 to 1.7.0 Upgrade - Standalone Version(in-built database)

Tags: migration, upgrade, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm running WSO2 API Manager 1.6 Standalone. As it is. Without a separate database. I'm using the in-built database. I went through the below question on SO.

[WSO2 API Manager - Upgrade 1.6.0 to 1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871458/wso2-api-manager-upgrade-1-6-0-to-1-7-0)

But it focuses on API Manager 1.6.0 with MySQL database. What I want to know it what are the files to be updated and how. Existing data to be migrated to the newer version.

How can I migrate WSO2 API Manager 1.6.0 to 1.7.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not recommanding running WSO2 product with default file system based H2 database in production. You should consider to use production ready databases like MySQL, MSSQL, etc.

You can check the README for the resource migration from [Data Migration 1.6.0 to 1.7.0](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.8.0/modules/distribution/resources/migration-1.6.0_to_1.7.0/). You may need to run those update scripts available for H2 database.

### **UPDATE** : How to run the update script for H2 database for WSO2 API Manager

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2AM_DB -script /path/to/file/h2.sql
```

You should run this within your API-M HOME directory.

Comment: I went through the README but it does not state anything about the H2 migration. +1 for the quick response.

Comment: what does it do? I don't get it. does it do the complete H2 migration to the newer version ?

Comment: @Techi, The newer version have some DB updtaes, so, you have run the update script against your database.

Comment: Which means 1st I have to get the data out of the old AM and insert them into new AM.

Comment: As I mentioned, using this default file based H2 database is not recommanded. Since the database kept as files inside the AM, you have to run the update script againt your old AM database and point that database to your new AM instance.

Comment: Okay thanks, one last clarification to be made, Do I have to carry out all the steps in the link you have provided?

Comment: @Techie, Yes, otherwise, you may break some functionalities.